# Show a selectList by javascript/JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I'm trying to raise an event to open a selectList when the page loads. It's possible?

Thank you

edit.

ok, i will try to explain a little bit more i have a selectList like this:

```
<select id="myID" name="myName"> 
   <option value=""></option> 
   <option  value="CL">Option1</option> 
   <option value="CM">Option2</option> 
   <option value="CP">Option3</option> 
</select>
```

When i click on it, the selectList shows and i can click the option i want, but i want to raise that 'click' event in the page load so the user dont need to click in the "button" to show the list. i tried some functions of JQuery like .trigger() but no one works. –

Comment: plz elaborate in more details..what you wants?

Comment: Pls mention in EDIT of your Question with proper formatting. Maybe post your code on jsfiddle

Comment: ok, i think now the question is easier to understand

Comment: @Asiereiki are you trying to load list using jquery on form load rather than button click. am i right

Comment: the values of the list are static. I only want to show the "dropdownlist" on the form load as you say.

Comment: means this `dropdown` is disable mode.. in page load button click event fire to show this `List`?

Answer (score 1):

use `change` Event in Drodownlist and using [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) fire your event.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
         $('select[id*=myID]').bind('change',function(){

             alert('Event Fire');
            //do stuff
       });

       $('select[id*=myID]').trigger('change');
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TC3jU/6/)** check here.